# partial fraction decomposition, decompose denominator

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I would like to compute the following integral 
$$\displaystyle \int_{\gamma} \frac{z-1}{z(z-i)(z-3i)}dz$$ where $\gamma$ is the curve $|z-i|=1/2$

> **My question:** How can i decompose it to partial fraction, i tried to multiply the nominator with $(z)(z-i)(z-3i)$ so $$A\cdot(z-i)(z-3i)+B\cdot z(z-3i)+C\cdot z(z-i)=z-1$$ and then compare the variable ,but really takes a lot of time,  is there another way to find $A$,$B$ and $C$? such thatwe have the equality:

$$\displaystyle \int_{\gamma} \frac{z-1}{z(z-i)(z-3i)}dz=\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\left( \frac{A}{z}dz+ \frac{B}{z-i}dz+ \frac{C}{z-3i}\right)dz$$

I got by comparing the following:

$$\displaystyle \int_{\gamma}\left( \frac{1}{3z}dz+ \frac{i-1}{2(z-i)}dz+ \frac{3i-1}{6(z-3i)}\right)dz$$

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{z-1}{z(z-i)(z-3i)}=\frac{A}{z}+\frac{B}{z-i}+\frac{C}{z-3i}$$

To get $A$ multiply both sides by $z$ and then take the limit as $z\to 0$ in both sides:

Let $f(z)=\displaystyle{\frac{z-1}{z(z-i)(z-3i)}}$. Then, par example

$$ z\cdot f(z) = A +z\cdot\frac{B}{z-i}+z\cdot\frac{C}{z-3i} $$

$$ (z-i)\cdot f(z) = (z-i)\cdot\frac{A}{z}+B+(z-i)\cdot\frac{C}{z-3i} $$

$$ (z-3i)\cdot f(z) = (z-3i)\cdot\frac{A}{z} +(z-3i)\cdot\frac{B}{z-i}+C $$

Taking the corresponding limit in each case gives you:

$$A=\underset{z\to 0}{\lim}{\ z\cdot f(z)}=\frac{1}{3}$$

$$B=\underset{z\to i}{\lim}{\ (z-i)\cdot f(z)}=\frac{i-1}{i(-2i)}=\frac{i-1}{2}$$

$$C=\underset{z\to 3i}{\lim}{\ (z-3i)\cdot f(z)}=\frac{3i-1}{3i(2i)}=\frac{3i-1}{-6}=\frac{1-3i}{6}$$

Also, just starting eith your equation:

$$A\,(z-i)(z-3i)+B\,z(z-3i)+C\,z(z-i)=z-1$$

You can:

1) Evaluate at $z=0$ both sides to isolate after $A$

2) Evaluate at $z=i$ both sides to isolate after $B$

3) Evaluate at $z=3i$ both sides to isolate after $C$

Comment: thankyou so much!!!! i forgot to multiply it with what that makes it zero to isolate it,, thanks!! really helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [residue method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Residue_method)

$$ A = \operatorname{Res}\big(f(z),0\big) = \lim_{z\to 0} z\ f(z) = \frac{1}{3} $$

and so on

Comment: thankyou so much i know i can use residue, but having trouble finding the partial fraction, thanks so much!!!!